# HTTP request doesn't work (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

This is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbLEEE

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "anyURL", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I don't know how to finish my HTTP Request.
When I enter a random URL I always get the same ResponseCode.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot read a URL from a different domain unless that domain has been specifically configured to allow access.  Look in the browser error console.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: That means that you (or your backend guy) should configure the server in that way to allow making requests from your localhost IP.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know anything about server configuring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do HTTP requests with js in localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225107/how-to-do-http-requests-with-js-in-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute this using server, if you want to execute it without server then you need Internet explorer with enabled Activex control. you need to copy this script and paste it between  tag and save it as a html file. open the file with Internet Explorer.

```js
window.onload = addElement;


function addElement() {
 // create a new div element 
 // and give it popup content 
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 var texts;
 
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
 function()
 {
  
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
  {
   texts = xmlhttp.responseText;
   
  }
  else
  {
   texts = 'Waiting for response...';
  }
  newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup" style=" position: fixed;top: 15%;width: 800px;height: 200px;margin: auto;z-index: 99999;display: block;left:25%;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 4px #000;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 160px;">' + texts + '</div><button style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://soundcloud.com/jbadminton/lol", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 
 

 // Add The Background cover
 var BG = document.createElement("div");
 //BG.style.background-color = 'black';
 BG.style.width = '100%';
 BG.style.height = '100%';
 BG.style.background = 'black';
 BG.style.position = 'fixed';
 BG.style.top = '0';
 BG.style.left = '0';
 BG.style.opacity = '0.7';
 BG.style.zIndex = '99900';
 BG.style.display = 'none';
 BG.setAttribute("id", "bgcover");
  
 // add the newly created elements and its content into the DOM 
 document.body.appendChild(BG);
 document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, BG);
 // open popup onload
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
 var el = document.getElementById('popup');
 var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
 el.style.display = 'block';
 BG.style.display = 'block';
}

function tostoring() {
 window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Sms%20management%20systeem/testing/storing.php';
}

function closePopup() {
 var el = document.getElementById('popup');
 var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
 el.style.display = 'none';
 BG.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object which you should use is `XMLHttpRequest`. Example:

```
    function getURL(url, callback) {  

    // it makes one XMLHttpRequest object, 
    //which will be used for all the AJAX queries.

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if ((e.target.readyState === 4) && (e.target.status === 200) || (e.target.status < 299)) {
     callback(e.target.responseText);
        }
    });

    xhr.send(null); // send requests
}
```

Also, try to work with `debugger;` in your code to see what everything in your code does, as well with `console.log()` if it's easier for you. Open your Network tab in DevTools console and will see your network queries.